# working with two RDDs apache spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am using calliope i.e. spark plugin to connect with cassandra. I have created 2 RDDs which looks like

`class A 
  val persistLevel = org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK
  val cas1 = CasBuilder.cql3.withColumnFamily("cassandra_keyspace", "cassandra_coulmn_family 1")
  val sc1 = new SparkContext("local", "name it any thing ")
  var rdd1 = sc.cql3Cassandra[SCALACLASS_1](cas1)
  var rddResult1 = rdd1.persist(persistLevel)`

`class B
  val cas2 = CasBuilder.cql3.withColumnFamily("cassandra_keyspace",  "cassandra_coulmn_family 2")
  var rdd2 = sc1.cql3Cassandra[SCALACLASS_2](cas2)
  var rddResult2 = rdd2.persist(persistLevel)`

somehow following code base which creates a new RDD using the other 2 is not working. Is it possible that we cannot iterate with 2 RDDs together?

Here is the code snippet which is not working -

```
case class Report(id: Long, anotherId: Long)

  var reportRDD = rddResult2.flatMap(f => {
    val buf = List[Report]()
    **rddResult1.collect().toList**.foldLeft(buf)((k, v) => {
      val buf1 = new ListBuffer[Report]
      buf ++ v.INSTANCE_VAR_FROM_SCALACLASS_1.foldLeft(buf1)((ik, iv) => {
        buf1 += Report(f.INSTANCE_VAR_FROM_SCALACLASS_1, iv.INSTANCE_VAR_FROM_SCALACLASS_2)
      })
    })
  })
```

while if I replace the bold thing and initialize a val for it like -

```
val collection = rddResult1.collect().toList

var reportRDD = rddResult2.flatMap(f => {
    val buf = List[Report]()
    **collection**.foldLeft(buf)((k, v) => {
      val buf1 = new ListBuffer[Report]
      buf ++ v.INSTANCE_VAR_FROM_SCALACLASS_1.foldLeft(buf1)((ik, iv) => {
        buf1 += Report(f.INSTANCE_VAR_FROM_SCALACLASS_1, iv.INSTANCE_VAR_FROM_SCALACLASS_2)
      })
    })
  })
```

it works, is there any explaination?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: That is a whole lot of code that looks incidental to the question. Mind cleaning it up? You will find the same behavior without mixing in Cassandra, and the complexity inside `foldLeft`. It would make a nice question otherwise!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mixing a transformation with an action. The closure of the `rdd2.flatMap` is executed on the workers, while `rdd1.collect` is an 'action' in Spark lingo and delivers data back to the driver. So, informally, you could say that the data is not there when you try to flatMap over it. (I don't know enough of the internals -yet- to pin-point the exact root-cause)

If you want to operate on both RDDs distributedly, you should join them using one of the join functions (join, leftOuterJoin, rightOuterJoin, cogroup).

E.g.

```
val mappedRdd1 = rdd1.map(x=> (x.id,x))
val mappedRdd2 = rdd2.map(x=> (x.customerId, x))

val joined = mappedRdd1.join(mappedRdd2)
joined.flatMap(...reporting logic..).collect
```

Comment: thanks for the help, but somehow I am not getting join function available with RDDs. However, uning `new PairRDDFunctions(rdd1).join(rdd2)` worked.

Comment: you should `import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._`  and map your original rdd to a pairRDD. Join is done on the key, which is the first element of the tuple in the PairRDD. Using the example I gave above: `val mappedRdd1 = rdd1.map(x=> (x.id,x))` for a natural PK on your data model will do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

You can operate on RDDs in the application. But you cannot operate on RDDs in the executors (the worker nodes). The executors cannot give commands to drive the cluster. The code inside `flatMap` runs on the executors.

In the first case, you try to operate on an RDD in the executor. I reckon you would get a `NotSerializableException` as you cannot even send the RDD object to the executors. In the second case, you pull the RDD contents to the application, and then send this simple `List` to the executors. (Lambda captures are automatically serialized.)